# How to copy non-consecutive rows with a loop [vba]?

Tags: vba, excel

So I currently made code to go through a column and then check if the value at the cell meets the criteria or not. If yes, the code is supposed to copy the entire row or add that row to the clipboard. But the problem I have right now is that if there are multiple cells that fit the criteria, the end result is only the very last row that I copied. How can I fix this problemm?

```
wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
wbSrc.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Do While wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G").Value <> Empty
    If InStr(wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G").Value, LogID) Then
        wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Range(wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G"), wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "J")).Copy
    End If
    j = j + 1
Loop

wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
wbSrc.Activate

Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbSrc = Nothing
```

So if row 1, 4, 9, 50, 74, 90, 150 fits the criteria, that code only copies (adds to the clipboard) row 150. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the Copy in the Loop.

```
wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
wbSrc.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim idx as Integer
idx = 1
    Do While wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G").Value <> Empty
        If InStr(wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G").Value, LogID) Then
            wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Range(wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "G"),wbSrc.Worksheets("R").Cells(j, "J")).Copy

            wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & idx).PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            idx = idx +1
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop


wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
wbSrc.Activate

Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbSrc = Nothing
```